# Perform non-spatial queries on DB tables of a RDBMS connected with arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-task

Is it possible to use the arcgis infrastructure so as to perform queries on DB tables that do not contain spatial information?

For example, considering I have a RDBMS where I have a table namely "Articles" with no geographic info. 
Could I perform a query by article title through arcgis, so as to avoid following different  search/filtering approaches for spatial and non spatial data ?

Comment: Take a look at this Q/A, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript

Comment: I dont want to perform a DB query using javascprit. My issue is to perform query through the ArcGis JS API and using QueryTasks , Query Objects or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add any non-spatial table to your gis-service (mxd) and access it through the REST interface.
*Query Layer Requests* for example work as expected.